# Laravel: How to set limit for my model class so that it can't be called directly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

The application I am working on has a wrapper(DAO) for each model class. The model itself is derived from Eloquent class. The issue is that junior developers keep calling methods like `ModelClass:Where()` or `ModelClass::find()` rather than using `DAOClass:DaoMethod()`. How can I restrict in my class that implementor of class can't do something like `ModelClass::where()`?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I see no language mechanism to restrict this. But you can always restrict JUNIOR giving him a hard time if he is not understand.

Answer (score 0):

The [final](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) keyword should do the trick. Just make all your desired `DAOClass` methods final. That way, once they are called from a class which extends your `DAOClass`, they will get a fatal error.

Comment: `DAOclass is` not extending Model Class. `Modelclass` is already public.

Comment: I thought that ```ModelClass``` was extending your ```DAOClass```. If this is not the case, then I also believe that you cannot prevent this situation. 
You should probably create your coding standards and force the juniors to follow them.

Comment: or make `ModelClass` abstract and extend it via `DAOClass`?

Comment: @Volatil3 ```ModelClass``` should the name of the class for every single model you have out there, isn't it? If this is so, you will have to do this for every single model -- it doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: So how else I implement DAO to: 1)Make it Db agonistic 2) Access limitation?

Comment: This is rather a hard task when you put it like that. In Laravel, one can always create his own model and make it extend Eloquent. This makes it impossible to prevent a person from using a custom model class. You should probably find another ways to do this. One approach I can think of is to force the juniors to open merge requests (if using git) before submitting their code. This way you can review it and return it for modifications if you see them using the wrong methods.